# Ansible の shell のヒアドキュメントについて

Tags: bash, ansible

以下のような ansible のレシピを書いたのですが ansible-playbook を実行すると SyntaxError になって失敗します
(シェルの中身は AWS inspector の推奨対応をコピーしたもので bash に貼り付けると実行できます）

```
shell: |
for user in `awk -F: '($3 < 1000) {print $1 }' /etc/passwd` ; do
  if [ $user != ""root"" ]; then
    usermod -L $user
    if [ $user != ""sync"" ] && [ $user != ""shutdown"" ] && [ $user != ""halt"" ]; then
      usermod -s /sbin/nologin $user
    fi
  fi
done
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/shell_module.html
こちらに複数行のシェル書き方があったので真似してみたんですが
`shell: |`
はヒアドキュメントというわけではないんでしょうか

エラーメッセージは以下になります

```
FAILED! => {"reason": "Syntax Error while loading YAML.\n  expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ec2-user/git/ansible/roles/inspector/tasks/user.yml': line 17, column 50, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  shell: |\n  for user in `awk -F: '($3 < 1000) {print $1 }' /etc/passwd` ; do\n                                                 ^ here\nThis one looks easy to fix. It seems that there is a value started\nwith a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended\nwith the same kind of quote. For instance:\n\n    when: \"ok\" in result.stdout\n\nCould be written as:\n\n   when: '\"ok\" in result.stdout'\n\nOr equivalently:\n\n   when: \"'ok' in result.stdout\"\n"}
```

Comment: ドキュメントの例を見る限り、ヒアドキュメントではなくパイプに見えます。

Comment: エラーメッセージは正確に記載してください。

Comment: > ヒアドキュメントではなくパイプ　そうなのですね。大人しくスクリプトにして対象インスタンスにコピーして実行することにします

Comment: 現状のタイトルと本文だけでは真にやりたい事(=目的)がいまいち読み取れ無い気がします。

Comment: @cubick ansible-playbookで採用されているYAML形式の構文に関する質問であり、タイトルと本文はおおよそ適切です。むしろシェルの`|`パイプとは無関係です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

エラーメッセージがJSON文字列で表現されているので、エスケープを外すと

```
Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'

The error appears to be in '/home/ec2-user/git/ansible/roles/inspector/tasks/user.yml': line 17, column 50, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:
  shell: |
  for user in `awk -F: '($3 < 1000) {print $1 }' /etc/passwd` ; do
                                                 ^ here
This one looks easy to fix. It seems that there is a value started
with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended
with the same kind of quote. For instance:
    when: "ok" in result.stdout

Could be written as:

   when: '"ok" in result.stdout'

Or equivalently:

   when: "'ok' in result.stdout"
```

と書かれています。メッセージ通りであれば、

```
  shell: |
  for user in `awk -F: '($3 < 1000) {print $1 }' /etc/passwd` ; do
```

と、`shell:`行と同じ高さで記述していますでしょうか？

YAML形式はインデントで表現するため、スクリプトコードを一段下げる必要があります。

Comment: その通りでした。インデントは必要なのですね。うまく実行できました。